# How to update the TODAY function in Google Sheets every day (without me openning the sheet)

Tags: function, date, google-sheets

Is it possible to create some kind of a trigger, so my sheet updates automatically? I want to update the `=today()` functions in my google-sheet every day (without me opening the sheet). At this moment the dates only update, when I open the document.

Comment: Not challenging you, but I have to ask; why do you care what it is while closed? What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

- go to **File**
- select **Spreadsheet settings...**

[image: 0]